# Remove duplicates and add column values in python in csv

Tags: python, csv

I have two columns in my csv:  One is displaying colors and other column shows the count of colors.

```
color | count
red | 2
red | 5
green | 7
blue | 9
green | 3
orange | 5
```

I want to remove the duplicates from first column but sum up the corresponding values of the color. How to do this using python? I want the output in a csv.

Output expected

```
color | count
red | 7
green | 10
blue | 9
orange | 5
```

This is my code:

```
import csv reader=csv.reader(open('cu.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')  
writer=csv.writer(open('cu-clean.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')  
lastnames = set()  
for row in reader: if row[1] not in lastnames: writer.writerow(row)  
lastnames.add( row[1] )`
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde

I tried doing something like this. This is not working in anyway I wanted. I am a beginner in python and tried doing this.


    import csv
    reader=csv.reader(open('cu.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
    writer=csv.writer(open('cu-clean.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
    lastnames = set()
    for row in reader:
    if row[1] not in lastnames:
    writer.writerow(row)
    lastnames.add( row[1] )`

Comment: Sorry cannot fix by code block correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    colors = {}

    index = 0
    for row in reader:
        if index == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            color = row[0]
            count = row[1]

            if color in colors:
                colors[color] += int(count)
            else:
                colors[color] = int(count)
        index += 1

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in colors.iteritems():
        writer.writerow({header[0]: k, header[1]: v})
```

This is saving a dictionary for all of the colors and how many times they appeared, and then just writing the dictionary to the file.
You can change the delimiter to whatever you want (seems like you used "|")

(tested on python 2.7)

Comment: Yes thank you. This works. But can you explain as to where the sum of the values corresponding to colors is are happening?

Comment: if color in colors:
                colors[color] += int(count)
            else:
                colors[color] = int(count)
This checks if the current color is already inside the dictionary. If it's not, then it will enter it for the first time with the corresponding value. If it is already inside, then it will sum up the previous value with the new one.